# Multiple UIView types in one UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I'd like to load a plain UIView, a UIWebView and a UITableView all in the same nib.  Is that possible in the same UIViewController?  Is it possible to assign multiple UIViewControllers to the same Window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something close is possible. I recently answered [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585489/multiple-views-in-one-window) about multiple views in one window; the approach for having multiple view controllers is very similar, although they do need separate nib or xib files.

The way to do it is as follows:

1. Instantiate all the various controllers you need
2. Add the view of each controller to the parent view or window, as I answered in your previous question

Programmatically, it would look something like (repeated for each view controller you want to add):

```
// With some UIWindow *window
MyViewController *vc = [[[MyViewController alloc] 
                         initWithNibName:@"MyNib" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[window addSubview:vc.view];
```

Keep in mind you may need to adjust the `frame` property of the view before you add it, depending on where in the parent view or window you want to place it.

Comment: Tim, thanks a lot.  I didn't realize the relationship between the two questions.  I see the correlation now.