# Changing Views From Inside App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a one View Controller Called ThemeViewController with three nibs, all of which are a different theme.

I want to change the nib simply by hitting a button from within the app.  I placed this method from within the ThemeViewController class.

```
- (IBAction)switchTheme {
      self = [[ThemeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"theme_1" bundle:nil];   
}
```

Any help or suggestions? Thanks

Comment: instead of changing the nib, make three different views and add the different views to the main view as subviews...see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598091/multiple-uiview-types-in-one-uiviewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yourNibName" owner:self options:nil];
```