# Push more than 1 UIViewController at once

Tags: iphone

How do i push more than 1 UIViewController at once?

Comment: not sure, but this thread might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585489/multiple-views-in-one-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can push views in - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated method in every view controller.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the best way to do this is to use the setViewControllers:animated: method.  For example, here's a method which you can use to have a view controller push an array of view controllers:

```
- (void)pushViewControllers:(NSArray *)vcs animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSMutableArray *vcArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
    [vcArray addObjectsFromArray:vcs];

    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:vcArray animated:animated];
}
```

The last object in the array `vcs` will animate on to the screen, but the other view controllers in the array will precede it on the view controller stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `[self.navigationController pushViewController: foo animated: NO]` multiple times to build up a stack of controllers.