# Create Custom UIView

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uiview

In my App inside a view there are 4 `UIView` with circular corner each in four corners of the view. inside each view there are three `labels` with different title. can any one tell me how can I Customize my Own `View`?

Comment: What exactly you want, round the corner add view?? WHAT?

Comment: This is possible a Duplicate....... But anyways..... go through older post..... you will get solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585489/multiple-views-in-one-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have rounded corners by accessing the layers property of the view.

```
[view.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
[view.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Having no idea what you're asking whatsoever, I'd recommend you check out [this page in Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Can you give me Some important link how to customize UIView?

Comment: Create a custom class of UIView inherited from UIView and use it on your own way.